# Canon camera clicking when turned on,It says there is a lens error,Turns off

Tags: error

I dropped my camera on the lens. It did not take pictures after. I turned it off and when I tried to turn it on it said lens error and made a clicking noise and turned off. My camera is a canon IXY 800 IS Digital.

Comment: Personal advice, this is 18 years old model. Just buy new camera. And most of the contemporary phones can do better photos.

Comment: There isn't really a question here - you are just describing how you broke your camera. With respect, what do you expect anyone to say to you here? It either needs to be repaired or replaced. Probably repair is not economically viable. Hopefully you recorded plenty of nice memories with it, but as Romeo suggests, after 18 years, it's high time to move on to a newer, better model.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question, it is more than doubtful that this is fixable by any answer

Answer (score 1):

And your question is...?

Yes, sounds like you've broken it.  If the lens was removable you could try swapping in a replacement, but I think it's integral on this camera. You could try manipulating the lens when turning on.  Otherwise repair is very unlikely to be economical.  Sorry.   Time for a new camera.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this camera was repairable 18 years ago when it was released the parts are definitely not available any more and are very likely to be specific to same very old cameras.